# Value of providing images in multiple resolutions and how to describe them in XAML

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm porting a WP7 app to WP8 and icons have become blurry on non-WVGA screens. I want the app to have crystal clear icons. I've been reading the [Multi-resolution guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206974%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) on MSDN for guidance on doing this, but it's not entirely clear to me yet.

- It recommends providing only WXGA assets. Is there any value in providing images for each resolution (ex.: logo.screen-wvga.png, -wxga.png, -720p.png)? It's fairly easy for me to generate each resolution, and I'm not concerned by increasing the package size. I wonder if assets are expected to have a higher quality (sometimes?) if the OS doesn't scale them down. This isn't for a background image that needs to fill the screen area -- it's for a logo and small-medium icons used throughout the app.
- Let's say I only make a WXGA version of an icon. What's the proper way to describe the image in XAML? If my original image for WVGA screens on WP7 was 37px by 36px, I generated WXGA one by multiplying dimensions by 1.6; my image is now 59px by 58px (rounded). If I have `<Image Source="MyWxgaIcon.png"/>` and run it on the WXGA emulator, the OS blows it up by another 1.6x factor. It seems like I need to specify the dimensions of the original, pre-scaling image like this `<Image Soruce="MyWxgaIcon.png" Width="37" Height="36"/>`. This seems unnatural as the asset doesn't have those dimensions -- is this the expected way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WP8 multi-resolution works in a way that you always have a width of 480 logical pixels (and 800 or 853.3 px height) and that all elements are described using the logical pixels. 
There's no built-in way to provide multi-res assets. The recommended way is to provide assets for high resolution and let the OS scale them down. More complex solutions need some code.

Also see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206974(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same confusion a couple of days ago. The 'Multi-resolution apps for Windows Phone 8' article did not actually point out clearly how we could let XAML display properly images if there were only WXGA assets provided. I found the solution through 2 following tutorials:

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-Phone-8-Multiple-Screen-Resolutions.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970269.aspx

It turned out that you did not need to declare explicitly the Height:

```xml
<Image Source="MyWxgaIcon.png" Width="37" />
```

However, this way is supposed to consume more memory when you run app on WVGA device. In that case, the image is scaled down to display but real size in pixels still remains constant.

So a more optimizing way is:

```xml
<Image Width="37">
    <Image.Source>
        <BitmapImage DecodePixelWidth="37" UriSource="MyWxgaIcon.png" />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```